# Catastrophic failure error when client connected server on datasnap delphi 7

Tags: delphi, com, datasnap

I've developed a client\server program with `Delphi 7` and `Datasnap` occasionally my client is not connect to the server and makes an error `Catastrophic failure`.

I have tested client with (Dcom,socket,web) but the client is not connected until my server program get restart then the client becomes connected.

My server is ms windows 2008 server r2 and the client connected with the server on "COM" and keep the connection open.

Comment: What's your question?  It sounds like you have a problem with your server.  Please add to your q what have you done to diagnose it.

Comment: Does your client try to keep the connection open over a long time, or is it using a `try Connect and DoSomething finally Disconnect` pattern? (Please show some code)